# RxJava2 with JUnit: no exceptions thrown in tests

Tags: android, junit, rx-java, rx-java2

The code below won't crash when running in JUnit environment. But it crashes when running in the app. I can see error logs in the console, but tests are marked as passed.

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    Observable observable = Observable.error(new RuntimeException());
    observable.subscribe();
  }
```

So, the question is: how to make it crash in JUnit. Because yeah, if something doesn't work in the app it's a good thing if it doesn't work in the unit tests also :)

And in this example I have direct access to the observable. But in my real tests I don't have that. Real observables are just internal details of classes that being tested. The most thing I can to do is to inject schedulers or something.

So, how to make it crash without having direct access to the observable?

Also, I've just checked this code doesn't crash either:

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    Observable observable = Observable.error(new RuntimeException());
    observable.subscribe(new Consumer() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
        throw new RuntimeException();
      }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        throw new RuntimeException();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Such usages no longer throw synchronously in 2.x but end up in the plugin handler for errors. By default, the handler prints the stacktrace so that's why you see errors printed to the console but no failure in test. Otherwise, only fatal exceptions such as StackOverflowError propagate.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you, that's interesting, it's RxJava2 specific then. Are there any way to detect that errors somehow and make tests fail?

Comment: You have to design for that. Also you shouldn't really throw in the consumer and if that's likely, use your own try-catch around the problematic code inside the consumer's onNext or lambda.

Comment: @akarnokd Design how? I'm out of ideas.I don't throw in consumers and it's not likely. But I have dozens of these consumers in my app and programming errors occur. Especially during development. And then they occur I want to be able to catch them immediately. During execution of unit tests.

Comment: @akarnokd Should I modify plugin handlers somehow? Or implement custom operator and use lift()? Or should I use custom Observer? How make it throw synchronously? I'll appreciate any hint. I'll be able to dig further myself after that.

Comment: In our own unit tests, I hook into the onError and verify if there was an error [sent that way](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions/blob/55256044d7dae53142de8a06fb15c8365272d4b2/src/test/java/hu/akarnokd/rxjava2/operators/FlowableValveTest.java#L138). Otherwise, looking at your gist, I don't see why you want to test against failing consumers - that's their problem and your code is shielded as much as possible by RxJava.

Comment: @akarnokd That works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small trick I use to tackle this problem, is creating a JUnit4 TestRule class that setups a custom RxJava error handler so it can throw when an unhandled RxJava error occurs:

```java
/**
 * A rule that detects RxJava silent errors and reports them to JUnit
   (by throwing them).
 */
public class RxErrorRule implements TestRule {

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {

                Consumer<? super Throwable> previous = RxJavaPlugins.getErrorHandler();

                AtomicReference<Throwable> result = setupErrorHandler();

                try {
                    base.evaluate();
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(previous);
                }

                if (result.get() != null) {
                    throw result.get();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private AtomicReference<Throwable> setupErrorHandler() {
        AtomicReference<Throwable> result = new AtomicReference<>();

        RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                result.set(throwable);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

}
```

And in the unit test:

```java
public class YourRxTest {

    @Rule
    public RxErrorRule errorRule = new RxErrorRule();

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

According to akarnokd this is RxJava2 specific problem.

"Such usages no longer throw synchronously in 2.x but end up in the plugin handler for errors."

It is possible to check if any errors was thrown with this code

```
public static List<Throwable> trackPluginErrors() {
    final List<Throwable> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Throwable>());

    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable t) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TestSubscriber](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html)

```
    Observable observable = Observable.error(new RuntimeException());
    TestSubscriber testSubscriber = TestSubscriber.create();

    observable.subscribe(testSubscriber);

    testSubscriber.assertTerminalEvent();
    testSubscriber.assertError(RuntimeException.class);
```

Comment: That's looks good, but unfortunately I don't have access to the observable and to subscribe() call in my real tests. I'm not testing observables, I'm testing components that consists of observables.

Comment: And, I want to test that code of real subscriber works fine, so replacing it with TestSubscriber just defeats the purpose.

Comment: Why do you want to test internal details of a class? You should only test the public interfaces of classes.

Comment: Why do you think I'm testing internal details of a class? Observables and subscribers are internal details of my classes. When something crashes in this internal details while I'm testing public interface of the class I want my test fail.

Comment: Here is beter example of the situation: https://gist.github.com/rongi/16c2f5e4b494b0671c695007daa70984 My presenter crashes when observing result but my tests passs.

Comment: Expose your getData method to outer class and provide it via dependency injection. Then mock that class with mockito and verify different interactions on your view depending on value you receive from your data mock. I can provide a sample code in 30 min if I'm not clear.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. Mocking it has nothing to do with the problem in this question and it doesn't solve it. The crash is in subscribe code, not in observable code. Here is the updated gist: https://gist.github.com/rongi/16c2f5e4b494b0671c695007daa70984 The unit test is marked as successfull and there is no crash. There is crashlog in the logs though.

Comment: You shouldn't throw exceptions in your subscribe block. What you have to do is to modify your observable stream such that all your errors go into Consumer<Throwable> or you handle them by operators. That way you can verify that your Consumer<String> is not called. Take a look into this https://www.infoq.com/articles/Testing-RxJava

Comment: That exception is just a simulation of a situation when programming error occurred in subscriber. Like some kind of NullPointerException, or IndexOutOfBoundsException. In this case app will crash which is good. I want the unit tests to crash also.

Comment: And it's very important for me for unit tests to crash there. Because if I will forget to handle observable errors with operators, etc. then my app will crash but unit tests will not.

Comment: I have nothing to add to the latest @akarnokd comment.